# ¿Cómo guardo datos en un archivo creado .obj en java?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un problema con el siguiente programa, al momento de sobrescribir guarda los datos puestos. Pero una vez que sales del programa si le das a Leer sólo te muestran los datos anteriormente colocados y si le doy en agregar nuevos datos ya no los guarda. Agradeceria muchísimo la ayuda, gracias de antemano.

--------------CLASE 1------------

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Alumnos implements Serializable  {

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Alumnos(String nombre, int edad){
        super();
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.edad=edad;

    }
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }

}
```

--------------CLASE 2------------

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String cadena;
        Scanner entrada = null;
        char R=' ';
        System.out.println("¿Quieres leer o escribir?   A = Leer   B = Escribir");
        R = sc.next().charAt(0);
        File archivo = new File ("datos.obj"); 
        switch (R)
        {
        case 'A':
            if (!archivo.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("No hay archivo existente");
                System.out.println("¿Quieres crear un archivo nuevo?   A = Sí   B = No");
                char R2 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                if (R2 == 'A'){
                    archivo.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("¿Quieres sobre escribir o continuar con los datos? A= sobre escribir B = continuar ");
                     char R3 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                     if (R3=='A'){
                     sobreintrodatos();
                    }
                     if (R3=='B'){
                    guardarintrodatos();
                        }
                     else 
                     {
                         System.out.println("Cerrando programa ");
                     }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Cerrando programa ");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                leer();
                System.out.println("¿Quieres agragar nuevos datos?  A= Sí B = No ");
                 char R4 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                 if (R4=='A'){
                     System.out.println("¿Quieres sobre escribir o continuar con los datos? A= sobre escribir B = continuar ");
                     char R5 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                     if (R5=='A'){
                     sobreintrodatos();
                    }
                     if (R5=='B'){
                         guardarintrodatos();
                        }
                     else 
                     {
                         System.out.println("Cerrando programa ");
                     }
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     System.out.println("Cerrando programa ");
                 }
            }

        break;
        case 'B':
            if (!archivo.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("¿Quieres crear un archivo nuevo?   A = Sí   B = No");
                char R6 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                if (R6 == 'A'){
                    archivo.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("¿Quieres sobre escribir o continuar con los datos? A= sobre escribir B = continuar ");
                     char R7 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                     if (R7=='A'){
                     sobreintrodatos();
                    }
                     if (R7=='B'){
                         guardarintrodatos();
                        }
                     else 
                     {
                         System.out.println("Cerrando programa ");
                     }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("¿Quieres sobre escribir o continuar con los datos? A= sobre escribir B = continuar ");
                 char R8 = sc.next().charAt(0);
                 if (R8=='A'){
                 sobreintrodatos();
                 }
                 if (R8=='B'){
                     guardarintrodatos();
                     }
                 else 
                 {
                     System.out.println("Cerrando programa ");
                 }
            }
            break;
      }


    }
    public static void sobreintrodatos() throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0;
        char R=' ';
        String nom;
        //File f= new File("datos.obj");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("datos.obj");
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        do{
        try {
            System.out.println("Nombre:");
            nom = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Edad:");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            oos.writeObject(new Alumnos(nom,n));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }  

        System.out.println("¿Desea continuar ingresando datos?   A  = Sí   B = No");
        R = sc.next().charAt(0);

     }while(R=='A');
     System.out.println("Cerrando programa");
   }

    public static void guardarintrodatos() throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0;
        char R=' ';
        String nom;
        //File f= new File("datos.obj");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("datos.obj",true);

        do{
              ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        try {
            System.out.println("Nombre:");
            nom = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Edad:");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            oos.writeObject(new Alumnos(nom,n));
            oos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }  

        System.out.println("¿Desea continuar ingresando datos?   A  = Sí   B = No");
        R = sc.next().charAt(0);

     }while(R=='A');
     System.out.println("Cerrando programa");
   }
    public static void leer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ObjectInputStream entrada=null;    
            try {
                File f= new File("datos.obj");
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                entrada=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                while (true) {
                Alumnos p=(Alumnos) entrada.readObject();
                System.out.println("Nombre: " +p.getNombre()+" "+"Edad: " +p.getEdad());
                System.out.println("*******************************");
                                } 
            }
            catch (IOException io){
                System.out.println("Fin del archivo");
            }
            finally {
                entrada.close();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Lo pudiste solucionar?

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectOutputStream` y `ObjectInputStream` son clases con un comportamiento un poco especial.

Si haces un `new de ObjectOutputStream`, por el mero hecho de hacer el `new`, escribe unos bytes en el `stream` (en el fichero) a modo de cabecera. Luego ya va escribiendo las clases que tú quieras.

Lo mismo pasa con `ObjectInputStream`, por el mero hecho de hacer un new, intenta leer del `stream` (del fichero) esos bytes de cabecera.

Sabiendo esto, es importante que a la hora de escribir y a la hora de leer, lo hagas igual en cuanto a la creación de `ObjectInputStream` y `ObjectOutputStream`.

Si creas un único `ObjectOutputStream` para escribir todos los datos, debes crear un único `ObjectInputStream` para leer todos los datos.

Si creas un `ObjectOuputStream` cada vez que escribes un datos, debes crear un `ObjectInputStream` cada vez que lees un dato.

En tu caso que quieres poder ir añadiendo datos en varias sesiones, debes optar por la segunda opción. Para escribir deberías seguir este tipo de estructura, independientemente de que sea para añadir o sobreescribir

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("datos.obj");
do{
   // Crea el ObjectOutputStream dentro del bucle
   ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   try {

      ...
   }
}
```

y para leer crea el ObjectInputStream dentro del bucle

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
do{
   // Crea el ObjectInputStream dentro del bucle
   entrada= new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   try {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo me sirvío hace un tiempo me lo encontré en https://mejorenjava.wordpress.com, como no se si todavía este posteado te lo dejo aqui:

**Escritura de ficheros en Java**

Para la escritura en un fichero tenemos la clase **BufferedWriter**, que a partir de un objeto de tipo **FileWriter**, nos proporciona el método append() para añadir toda la información. Esta clase incluso nos proporciona el método **newLine()** que crea un salto de línea en el fichero.

El fichero si no existe se crea y si existe, se elimina y se crea de cero. Si lo que se quiere hacer es añadir en un fichero ya existente, al crear el objeto **FileWriter** hay que recuerrir al constructor **FileWriter(String filename, boolean append)**. Con un true en el segundo parámetro, si el fichero existe, añade la información.

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
try {
 FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:/aaa.txt", true);
 bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  bufferedWriter.append(Integer.toString(i));
  bufferedWriter.newLine();
 }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
 try {
  if (bufferedWriter != null) {
   bufferedWriter.close();
  }
 } catch (Exception e2) {
  e2.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría crear un método que haga la serialización y deserialización en este caso lo haré como si estuviera en tu clase alumno, pero lo mejor sería una clase nueva para las operaciones de este tipo, como crear, borrar o actualizar.

```
public int serializa(List alumnos) {
    int res = 0; //Fracaso
    // Aqui se serializa el objeto alumno
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Alumnos.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(alumnos);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.printf("Objeto alumnos ha sido serializado /Alumnos.ser");
        res = 1;
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();

    }

    return res;
}

public List consultaLista() {
    int res = 0;
    //Deserialización del archivo Alumnos.ser
    List<Alumno> list = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Alumno.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        list = (List) in.readObject();     
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        res = 1;
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        System.out.println("No se encontró la clase del alumno");
        c.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Dentro de tu main:
Esto es para crear un nuevo archivo

```
Alumno alumno = new Alumno("Pedro", 15);
List<Alumno> lista = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
lista.add(alumno);
alumno.serializa(lista); //se ha guardado el archivo
```

Si ya tienes el archivo y quiere añadir un nuevo alumno:

```
Alumno alumno = new Alumno("Pedro", 15); //necesitas un constructor vacio en tu clase Alumno
List<Alumno> lista = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
lista=alumno.consultaLista();
lista.add(alumno);
alumno.serializa(lista);
```

Si recuperas tu archivo, verás que fue añadido el alumno nuevo.
Puedes moficar los métodos a tu necesidad.